# Export Google Doc **with** suggested changes to plain text

Tags: google-docs, export-to-text

My research team uses "suggesting mode" in Google Doc to flag changes made to papers that we jointly write (in latex format/syntax). When I export the paper to "plain text", the text unfortunately ends up containing the *original* verbiage rather than the most recent version of *suggested changes*.  I need the same capability in Google Docs as MS Word provides, which is the "tracked changes" (suggesting mode edits) being exported into the text file without first having to click the "accept" button on the suggested changes beforehand.  **Is there an app that already exists or which I could write that would incorporate the suggested/tracked changes when exporting the Google Doc to plain text?**

Comment: This question is the very first one that I've ever posted on any forum.  What does the "-1" score mean?  How is it that my question could have a negative score without any comments?  Just curious...

Comment: Duplicate of [Programmatically temporarily altering a Google Docs and then replacing with the pre-altered version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647796/programmatically-temporarily-altering-a-google-docs-and-then-replacing-with-the). See the OP's "answer", below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be more complicated than I originally anticipated, which is why it is explained on a different (but related) Stack Overflow question.  The solution given for [Programmatically temporarily altering a Google Docs and then replacing with the pre-altered version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647796/programmatically-temporarily-altering-a-google-docs-and-then-replacing-with-the/38733001#38733001) also answers this question.